# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'

Tags: jax-ws, spring-ws

When running maven clean install, I get the following error:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'wss:binding'

I don't understand why this error appear since it's a copy-paste from the example on https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/. I also have xbean-spring v3.16 in my dependencies.

I checked http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd an element binding exists!

Here is the file I copied/pasted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
  xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.ws.soap.service.impl" />

    <wss:binding url="/service/desoteServicePort">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#desoteService" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

</beans>
```

What's wrong with my file?

Answer (score 3):

The namespaces don't match. You declared the namespaces:

```
<beans ...
  xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
  xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
```

but when you did the association with the schema locations you used a different namespace:

```
  xsi:schemaLocation=" ...

    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core    http://.../core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet http://.../servlet.xsd">
```

There is an extra "dev" in the namespace you declared that is not present in the namespace you associate with the XSD location.

You might be mixing up different versions of Spring.

Comment: The problem is that it's a pure copy/paste from the official website, and I can't make it work. There is a 404 with http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/*

Comment: As a namespace, the URL doesn't have to actually be functional. But if you are associating an instance with a Schema, which is the case here,  you need to declare the namespace (and prefix) with `xmlns` and then associate the namespace with a schema location. The namespace string must be identical (even an extra `/` will make it fail). Try to remove the `.dev` from the `xmlns` declarations.

Comment: Post the link to the site where you got the header from. And check your dependencies. Spring actually tries to read the schema locally from the JARs. The namespace is used to retrieve it. If you have the wrong version of Spring installed, it won't work.

Comment: The link is the first one on my question. I'll try to check my dependencies

Comment: The page contains an error. The namespaces have to match. There is a link to a sample application on the page, and it's different from the one shown. This is probably a working file: https://svn.java.net/svn/jax-ws-commons~svn/trunk/spring/test-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @helderdarocha, the sample works but the documentation is wrong.  Kind of amazed this hasn't been cleared up in ~a year since the last update to [JAX-WS Commons](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/).

That said, the header below (from [here](https://svn.java.net/svn/jax-ws-commons~svn/trunk/spring/test-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml)) works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's long time from question that have many answers, but here is the short answer that collect from these.

There are two problems that cause this error:

1. Wrong xsd definition in applicationContext.xml. It caused by copy and paste from this [doc](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/) . It must be:

   `http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd`

Note that **have dev in url in core and servlet**. Don't miss that

2. Use **right dependency for jaxws with spring library** in maven pom. Like this:

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
       <version>1.9</version>
       <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
               <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
     </dependency>`

Then everything work fine!